QGIS Elevation Profile issues when exporting to PDF
I have recently started using the elevation profile tool on QGIS however once I have my cross-section and move on to exporting it to PDF, the result is just the top left-hand corner of the graph. I am using chart ranges given by a colleague and left the other labels as they were. Export to image seems to work alright so not sure what is going on.
Can you point me in the right direction?


